# Nested attributes unpermitted parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `Bill` object, which has many `Due` objects. The `Due` object also belongs to a `Person`. I want a form that can create the `Bill` and its children `Dues` all in one page. I am trying to create a form using nested attributes, similar to ones in [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1).

Relevant code is listed below:

**due.rb**

```
class Due < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :person
    belongs_to :bill
end
```

**bill.rb**

```
class Bill < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :dues, :dependent => :destroy 
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :dues, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

**bills_controller.rb**

```
  # GET /bills/new
  def new
      @bill = Bill.new
      3.times { @bill.dues.build }
  end
```

**bills/_form.html.erb**

```
  <%= form_for(@bill) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :company %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :company %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :month %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :month %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :year %><br />
        <%= f.number_field :year %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
    <%= f.fields_for :dues do |builder| %>
        <%= render 'due_fields', :f => builder %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

**bills/_due_fields.html.erb**

```
<div>
    <%= f.label :amount, "Amount" %>        
    <%= f.text_field :amount %>
    <br>
    <%= f.label :person_id, "Renter" %>
    <%= f.text_field :person_id %>
</div>
```

**UPDATE to bills_controller.rb**
This works!

```
def bill_params 
  params
  .require(:bill)
  .permit(:company, :month, :year, dues_attributes: [:amount, :person_id]) 
end
```

The proper fields are rendered on the page (albeit without a dropdown for `Person` yet) and submit is successful. However, none of the children dues are saved to the database, and an error is thrown in the server log:

```
Unpermitted parameters: dues_attributes
```

Just before the error, the log displays this:

```
Started POST "/bills" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-10 00:16:37 -0700
Processing by BillsController#create as HTML<br>
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", 
"authenticity_token"=>"ipxBOLOjx68fwvfmsMG3FecV/q/hPqUHsluBCPN2BeU=",
 "bill"=>{"company"=>"Comcast", "month"=>"April ", 
"year"=>"2013", "dues_attributes"=>{
"0"=>{"amount"=>"30", "person_id"=>"1"}, 
"1"=>{"amount"=>"30", "person_id"=>"2"},
 "2"=>{"amount"=>"30", "person_id"=>"3"}}}, "commit"=>"Create Bill"}
```

Has there been some change in Rails 4?

Comment: Fix on formatting:
params.require(:bill).permit(:company, :month, :year, :dues_attributes => [:amount, :person_id])

Answer (score 193, accepted):

Seems there is a change in handling of attribute protection and now you must whitelist params in the controller (instead of attr_accessible in the model) because the former optional gem strong_parameters became part of the Rails Core.

This should look something like this:

```
class PeopleController < ActionController::Base
  def create
    Person.create(person_params)
  end

private
  def person_params
    params.require(:person).permit(:name, :age)
  end
end
```

So `params.require(:model).permit(:fields)` would be used

and for nested attributes something like

```
params.require(:person).permit(:name, :age, pets_attributes: [:id, :name, :category])
```

Some more details can be found in the [Ruby edge API docs](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) and [strong_parameters on github](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) or [here](http://rubysource.com/rails-4-quick-look-strong-parameters/)

Comment: I have changed my BillController to look like this:

    `def bill_params
      params.require(:bill).permit(:company, :month, :year, :dues_attributes[:amount, :person_id])
    end`

I am now getting this error:

**no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer**

Comment: Well, it helps to put the colon in the right place... This is exactly what needed to be done.  Thanks @thorsten-muller !

Comment: DON'T FORGET THE ID!!!!
`pets_attributes: [:id, :name, :category]`
Otherwise, when you edit, each pet will get created again.

Comment: You need to do `Person.create(person_params)` or it won't call the method.  Instead you'll get `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError`.

Comment: Also, if you want to destroy items from the form, you also need to whitelist the hidden `:_destroy` parameter. i.e. `pets_attributes: [:id, :name, :category, :_destroy]`

Comment: If you keep getting an error, make sure to add it at the end of the line (not in the middle). WRONG: :aaa, pets_attributes: [], :bbb. GOOD: :aaa, :bbb, pets_attributes: []

Comment: @Arcolye I literally just dealt with this issue and I was ***very*** confused to see my records being duplicated after an UPDATE. What blows my mind is that Rails requires the `:id`, even in Rails 4, when this (in my opinion) should be an ***implicit*** parameter. Rails is great, but this to me doesn't make any damn sense.

Comment: will this work if you are submitting multiple pet objects?

Answer (score 23):

From the docs

```
To whitelist an entire hash of parameters, the permit! method can be used

params.require(:log_entry).permit!
```

Nested attributes are in the form of a hash. In my app, I have a Question.rb model accept nested attributes for an Answer.rb model (where the user creates answer choices for a question he creates). In the questions_controller, I do this

```
  def question_params

      params.require(:question).permit!

  end
```

Everything in the question hash is permitted, including the nested answer attributes. This also works if the nested attributes are in the form of an array.

Having said that, I wonder if there's a security concern with this approach because it basically permits anything that's inside the hash without specifying exactly what it is, which seems contrary to the purpose of strong parameters.

Comment: Awesome, I cound't get to permit a range parameter explicitly, this save me some hours.

Comment: Yeah, using .permit! is usually seen as a potential security concern. You'd only really want to use it if the user is an admin, but even then I'd be wary of its use.

Comment: My nested attributes are in an array, too. Is `.permit!` the only option? I can't get it to work even with all the model's attributes permitted because it chokes on the array.

Answer (score 20):

or you can simply use

```
def question_params

  params.require(:question).permit(team_ids: [])

end
```

Answer (score 13):

Actually there is a way to just white-list all nested parameters.

```
params.require(:widget).permit(:name, :description).tap do |whitelisted|
  whitelisted[:position] = params[:widget][:position]
  whitelisted[:properties] = params[:widget][:properties]
end
```

This method has advantage over other solutions. **It allows to permit deep-nested parameters.**

While other solutions like:

```
params.require(:person).permit(:name, :age, pets_attributes: [:id, :name, :category])
```

Don't.

---

Source:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9454#issuecomment-14167664

Answer (score 3):

Today I came across this same issue, whilst working on rails 4, I was able to get it working by structuring my fields_for as:

```
<%= f.select :tag_ids, Tag.all.collect {|t| [t.name, t.id]}, {}, :multiple => true %>
```

Then in my controller I have my strong params as:

```
private
def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:id, :title, :content, :publish, tag_ids: [])
end
```

All works!

Comment: hi thank you @KingsleyIjomah - what if you want to white list specific attributes of the children?

Answer (score 1):

If you use a JSONB field, you must convert it to JSON  with .to_json (ROR)