# Rails 4/Devise/MongoDB: "Unpermitted parameters" using custom properties and strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

Trying to add a nested custom attribute, **Profile** (a Mongoid document), to my devise **User** class. When the Devise registration form is submitted, it should create both a **User** and a corresponding **Profile** object as well.

I'd like the end-result to look something like this in my MongoDB:

**User:**

```
{
  # Devise fields:
  "email": "my@email.com",
  ...
  # Custom field
  "profile" : "<object_id>"
}
```

**Profile:**

```
{
  "first_name": "Dave",
  ....
}
```

---

Unfortunately, I am receiving this in my console whenever I submit my registration. It successfully creates a User but fails to create an associated Profile.

```
Started POST "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-20 23:37:10 -0400
Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
Parameters:
   {"utf8"=>"✓",
   "authenticity_token"=>"awN2GU8EYEfisU0",
   "user"=>
       {"profile_attributes"=>
           {"first_name"=>"Dave",
           "birthday(2i)"=>"4",
           "birthday(3i)"=>"21",
           "birthday(1i)"=>"1933",
           "occupation_title"=>"Software Developer"},
        "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
        "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]",
        "email"=>"my@email.com"}}
Unpermitted parameters: profile_attributes
```

---

I have setup:

- Rails 4.0.0beta1, Ruby 2.0.0-p0
- Devise ('rails4' branch), Mongoid (from git)
- A custom Devise registrations controller to add a definition for strong parameters.

**models/user.rb:**

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
     :token_authenticatable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable

  field :email,              type: String, default: ''

  ...

  has_one :profile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
end
```

**models/profile.rb:**

```
class Profile
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  # Attributes
  # ----------
  field :slug,                type: String, default: '' # Acts as user-'friendlier' slug
  field :birthday,            type: DateTime, default: DateTime.now
  field :first_name,          type: String, default: ''
  field :occupation_title,    type: String, default: ''

  belongs_to :user
  embeds_many :photos
  has_one :occupation_industry, :as => :industry
end
```

**controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb**

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def resource_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :profile_attributes)
  end
  private :resource_params
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
devise_for  :users,
              :path => '',
              :path_names => {
                :sign_in => 'login',
                :sign_out => 'logout',
                :sign_up => 'register'
                },
              :controllers => {
                :registrations => "users/registrations",
                :passwords => "users/passwords"
              }
```

I have already looked at these related posts, they didn't seem to help:

- [Rails 4 Nested Attributes Unpermitted Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15919761/rails-4-nested-attributes-unpermitted-parameters)
- https://gist.github.com/kazpsp/3350730

---

**EDIT:**

Looks like Devise does actually support strong parameters in its 'rails4' branch (which is supposed to be merged into master in a few days.) Looking through the code, it appears you can override a params function for each action on devise controllers. For creating new users, its `sign_up_params` instead of `resource_params` in my example.

Despite changing this name to the proper one, it still didn't work... only whitelisting all parameters using this bang seemed to work:

```
def sign_up_params
  params.require(:user).permit!
end
```

Obviously, this kind of defeats the purpose of strong parameters... so now the question is how do I permit my nested attributes `profile_attributes` (as seen in my original question)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the exact same issue and overriding **sign_up_params** did work for me

```
def sign_up_params
   params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :other, :etc)
end
```

of course, the difference is in that mine are just scalar values, while you're trying to mass assign a relation... I guess that's where you should look for.

By the way, the documentations is still inexistint in this topic (too new), and code commnents suggest to override [devise_parameter_sanitizer](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/rails4/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L86), which isn't necessary.

Comment: In the class inheriting from **Devise::RegistrationsController**, this is how you override/extend it

Comment: Yep, this is the way to do it... for hashes (like my `profile_attributes`), you need to specify every embedded attribute explicitly by design. i.e. it looks something like: `params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, profile_attributes: [:first_name, :occupation_title])`

Answer (score 4):

I found a different method that allows **all the devise overriding logic and code to reside in the application controller**. This allows any and all custom params to be passed through for each devise action (sign in, sign up, update). I also add a parameter sanitizer for devise_invitable and handle that logic here (invite, accept_invitation). I've got custom params like avatar, avatar_cache, etc:

```
#application_controller.rb

  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected
  # There are just three actions in Devise that allows any set of parameters to be passed down to the model, 
  # therefore requiring sanitization. Their names and the permited parameters by default are:

  # sign_in (Devise::SessionsController#new) - Permits only the authentication keys (like email)
  # sign_up (Devise::RegistrationsController#create) - Permits authentication keys plus password and password_confirmation
  # account_update (Devise::RegistrationsController#update) - Permits authentication keys plus password, password_confirmation 
  # and current_password. More at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:accept_invitation) do |u|
      u.permit(:username,:validate_username, :password,:password_confirmation, :invitation_token)
    end
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:invite) do |u|
      u.permit(:name,:comments)
    end

    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
      u.permit(:username,:password,:password_confirmation)
    end
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) do |u|
      u.permit(:username,:email,:password,:password_confirmation,:phone, :validate_username, :avatar_cache, :remove_avatar, :current_password,:remember_me)
    end

    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) do |u|
      u.permit(:username,:email,:password,:password_confirmation,:phone, :validate_username,:avatar, :avatar_cache, :remove_avatar, :current_password)
    end
  end
```

Find and read more at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue  when login, it says: `Unpermitted parameters: password, remember_me`.
and because i have any controller that inheriting **Devise::SessionsController**, so i use my own [parameter sanitizer](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/rails4/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L86).

here is what i do:

Create a file in '#{Rails.root}/lib' fold, my is  `hzsapa_parameter_sanitizer.rb` and required in **config/application.rb**, then override `devise_parameter_sanitizer` method in **application_controller.rb**

**lib/hzsapa_parameter_sanitizer.rb**

```
class HzsapaParameterSanitizer < Devise::ParameterSanitizer
  def sign_in
    default_params.permit(auth_keys + [:password, :remember_me])
  end
end
```

You can override those method depends on your issue:

```
def sign_in
  default_params.permit(auth_keys)
end

def sign_up
  default_params.permit(auth_keys + [:password, :password_confirmation])
end

def account_update
  default_params.permit(auth_keys + [:password, :password_confirmation,    :current_password])
end
```

**config/application.rb**

```
require "hzsapa_parameter_sanitizer"
```

**app/application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def devise_parameter_sanitizer
    @devise_parameter_sanitizer ||= if defined?(ActionController::StrongParameters)
                                      HzsapaParameterSanitizer.new(resource_class, resource_name, params)
                                    else
                                      Devise::BaseSanitizer.new(resource_class, resource_name, params)
                                    end
  end
end
```

**Edit:** i just found the solution in devise README, you can follow it [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

I used your code and it worked for me!

Here is what I did

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => :create #, :if => Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }
  respond_to :json, :html, :xml

  def create
    user = User.new(devise_registrations_permitted_parameters)
    if user.save
      render :json=> user.as_json(:auth_token=>user.authentication_token, :email=>user.email,:name => user.name), :status=>201
      return
    else
      warden.custom_failure!
      render :json=> user.errors, :status=>422
    end
  end


  protected                                                            
    def devise_registrations_permitted_parameters
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end

end
```