# How set a boolean value using curl command to populate database, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl

I'm building a rails API and using curl to test and populate the Users table, and set the `admin` column to `true`. The default is `false`.

```
curl -XPOST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "user": { "email": "test@example.com", "password": "12345678", "admin": "TRUE" } }' http://localhost:3000/api/signup
```

The command above fails and `admin` value is always set to false no matter what. I have also tried `true`, `1`, `"1"` but nothing works.

Comment: Please show what's written to *development.log* while running this request

Comment: Yes, thank you. I'll definitely do that. As for now, I have found the answer already. See below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply just override Devise's `sign_up_params`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16196732/8050183

```
def sign_up_params
   params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :other, :etc)
end
```