# Unpermitted parameters for Dynamic Forms in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, railscasts

I'm new to Rails and built something based on this

http://railscasts.com/episodes/403-dynamic-forms

but I have a problem with storing data in the additional fields...
I have a ProductType object that has many ProductField objects. The ProductField object also belongs to a ProductType and Product object belongs to a ProductType.

So,new dynamic fields can easily be added via the constructor ProductType, but when I try to set data in this fields via Product controller nothing happens.

I am sure that problem is related to use strong parameters, but fix described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569999/unpermitted-parameters-for-double-nested-models-in-rails-4) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15919761/rails-4-nested-attributes-unpermitted-parameters) did't help.

**product.rb**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product_type
    serialize :properties, Hash
end
```

**product_type.rb**

```
class ProductType < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :fields, class_name: "ProductField"
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :fields, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**product_field.rb**

```
class ProductField < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product_type
end
```

**products_controller.rb**

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
    def new
    @product = Product.new(product_type_id: params[:product_type_id])
    end
    def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:name, :price, :product_type_id, {:properties => []})
    end
```

**product_type_controller.rb**

```
class ProductTypesController < ApplicationController
    def product_type_params
    params.require(:product_type).permit(:name, fields_attributes: [:id, :name, :field_type, :required, :product_type_id])
    end
```

In console log:
Unpermitted parameters: properties

```
Started PATCH "/products/4" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-04 22:54:59 +0400
Processing by ProductsController#update as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"my3ra60OUXexmmguk2eqRetizx3tWPMq04Z2PnODJMQ=", "product"=>{"product_type_id"=>"1", "name"=>"Product1", "properties"=>{"gjfghjf"=>"123", "123"=>[""]}, "price"=>"10"}, "commit"=>"Update Product", "id"=>"4"}
Product Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "4"]]
Unpermitted parameters: properties
```

P.S: maybe someone faced a similar problem when watching a podcast?

Comment: Can you post your form code? I see you are getting this: `"properties"=>{"gjfghjf"=>"123", "123"=>[""]}` in your return parameters. Properties is coming in as a hash of two items, one of which is an array. In your product_params it is expecting an array of permitted scalar values based on how it's written. Is this Railscast originally done using Rails 4?

Comment: If you want to test that it's a problem with how the params are constructed in either the form code or the `permit` statement you can do this: `params.require(:product).permit!`. It will whitelist everything. Good for testing but very bad for security so you'll want to sort it out at some point.

Comment: Yeap, params.require(:product).permit! really working, but it's very bad for security you are quite right..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to return a nested hash as a parameter you have to name the keys in the array in `permit`.

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
def new
@product = Product.new(product_type_id: params[:product_type_id])
end
def product_params
params.require(:product).permit(:name, :price, :product_type_id, {:properties => [:foo, :bar, :id]})
end
```

If you are generating the keys dynamically and can't code them into the `permit` statement then you need to use this style:

```
def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:name, :price, :product_type_id).tap do |whitelisted|
    whitelisted[:properties] = params[:product][:properties]
  end
end
```

It's not the most friendly code for a new user, I just finished the 3 course rails certificate at UW and they never even covered `.tap`.

This is not my work, I'm still just understanding the deeper parts of `.permit` like this. This is the blog entry I used: [Strong Parameters by Example](http://blog.sensible.io/2013/08/17/strong-parameters-by-example.html)

Comment: So did the code above work without any modification? If any mods were needed, leave a comment here with it and I'll change it so the answer is more accurate. If it worked perfect out of the box, well dang! A bit of luck on my part as I was just extrapolating from what I know about Strong Params and what I've read.