# Rails 4 permit nested attributes doesn't create/update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I convert my rails app(-v3.2.13) to rails 4.I use inherited resources gem's overwriting actions(create! and update!).I permit entire hash of the parameters,But It doesn't create/update the nested attributes.I need to permit the entire hash of the parameters.When i tried, i am getting the following error.Help me to solve this.

params

```
{"foo"=>{"name"=>"1@1", "detail"=>"123", foo1_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"_destroy"=>"", "name"=>"John", "url"=>"johnsmith.blogspot.com",foo2_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"min_time"=>"0", "max_entry"=>"340"}}, "foo3_attributes"=>{"_destroy"=>"", "hours"=>"01", "minutes"=>"00"}, "status"=>"ACTIVE"}}, "foo4_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"image"=>"0","id"=>"1097"}}}, "commit"=>"Save", "foo_id"=>"13", "id"=>"1467"}
```

My controller

```
def update
 update! do |success, failure|
  success.html { redirect_to foo_path }
 end
end

protected

def resource_params
 params.permit!
end
```

Foo Model

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for : foo1,foo2,foo3,foo4
has_many :foo1
has_many :foo2
has_many :foo3
has_many :foo4
```

Trace:

```
 Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3686ms

 ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (6 for 1..2)):
  app/controllers/foo_controller.rb:160:in `update'

 protected_attributes (1.0.3) lib/active_record/mass_assignment_security/persistence.rb:60:in `update_attributes'
inherited_resources (1.3.1) lib/inherited_resources/base_helpers.rb:78:in `update_resource'
inherited_resources (1.3.1) lib/inherited_resources/actions.rb:45:in `update'
app/controllers/partner_modules_controller.rb:160:in `update'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:445:in `block (2 levels) in _run__2668227825050344147__process_action__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:212:in `block in _conditional_callback_around_4134'
rails-observers (0.1.2) lib/rails/observers/action_controller/caching/sweeping.rb:73:in `around'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:283:in `_callback_around_4133'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:211:in `_conditional_callback_around_4134'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:444:in `block in _run__2668227825050344147__process_action__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:215:in `_conditional_callback_around_4135'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:443:in `_run__2668227825050344147__process_action__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:655:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.6.6.147) lib/new_relic/rack/error_collector.rb:43:in `call'
bullet (4.6.0) lib/bullet/rack.rb:13:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.6.6.147) lib/new_relic/rack/error_collector.rb:43:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.6.6.147) lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:22:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.6.6.147) lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:16:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
remotipart (1.2.1) lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__994999873434308059__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
quiet_assets (1.0.2) lib/quiet_assets.rb:18:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:81:in `block in pre_process'
thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `catch'
thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `pre_process'
thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:54:in `process'
thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:16:in `run'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:84:in `start'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `block in <top (required)>'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
script/rails:6:in `require'
script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: `params.require(:foo).permit(:attr_of_foo, :another_attr_of_foo, :foo1_attributes => [:attr_of_foo1, :more_attr_of_foo1], ..so forth)` doesn't work for you?

Comment: @jo3w Yes,I tried with `params.requir(:foo).permit(:name,:detail,foo1_attributes: [:name, :url])`,But i am getting wrong number of arguments error.I need to permit the entire hash.Am i missing anything here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371334/how-is-attr-accessible-used-in-rails-4/17371364#17371364

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be a bit late, but I just faced this myself. Hopefully it will save someone else some time.

**Using Rails 4.2.1**

The problem with the other answers here is that they don't take into consideration that there is an `array` for the value of `foo1_attributes`:

*(expanded example from OP)*

```
foo1_attributes"=> {
  "0"=> {
     "_destroy"=>"", "name"=>"John", "url"=>"johnsmith.blogspot.com"
  }
}
```

Because of this, you need to `permit` both `foo1_attributes` and `foo1_attributes[n]`

Here is how I successfully implimented similar functionality in my project:

*(formated to OP's exmaple above)*

```
def resource_params
  params.require(:foo)
    .permit(
      :id,
      :name,
      :detail,

      # has_many: :foo1s (Nested Attributes)
        { foo1_attributes: [
          # and the values for each `foo1` in `foo1_attributes`
          [
            :name,
            :url
          ]
        ]},

      # has_many: :foo2s (Nested Attributes)
        { foo2_attributes: [
          # and the values for each `foo2` in `foo2_attributes`
          [
            :min_time,
            :max_entry
          ]
        ]}

      # etc...
    )
```

Some other things to note...

- [The code for nested attributes which are arrays *may* need to be placed at the end of the `permit`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30285592/1522214)
- [Depending on your implementation, you may need to also include the `id` for each (see the top rated comment for this answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15920542/1522214)
- My specific implementation involved a `has_many :through`
- You'll also need to include `:_destroy` if you plan to delete them

Answer (score 6):

I faced a similiar kind of problem. Try doing the following. Assuming you need to update foo1. Use this for your strong parameters.

```
def foo_params
  params.require(:foo).permit(:foo1_attributes => [:bar1 , :bar2])
end
```

Do update by.

```
def update  
  if @foo.update_attributes!(foo_params)      
    redirect_to foo_path
  else
    render foo1_edit_path
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

hi you must use it this way:

`params.require( :foo ).permit( 
  :name, :details, 
  foo1_attributes: [ :_destroy, :name, :url, :id ], 
  foo2_attributes: [ :_destroy, :min_time, :max_entry, :id ]
)`

It may solve your problem.

Comment: here remember that id of nested attributes is not needed in case of creation but it is compulsary while updating nested attributes otherwise it will create a new copy of it for you. Thats why i added id field in nested attributes permit fields

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the [Strong Parameters README](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#permitted-scalar-values), you can use the `permit!` method to whitelist the entire hash of parameters as follows:

```
params.require(:foo).permit!
```

Please keep in mind the following quote from the README document linked when doing this:

> Extreme care should be taken when using permit! as it will allow all current and future model attributes to be mass-assigned.

Comment: It doesn't work.Still i am getting wrong number of aruguments error.

Comment: Can you post the full trace in your question when this error occurs.

Comment: @Mano, is that it?  There should be more because I don't see the error you are talking about.

Comment: @Mano, Please try calling `update!` with `resource_params` parameter, i.e. in your update action do `update!(resource_params) do |success, failure|`

Comment: Oh my god thank you! I have been writing endless permit(.....) calls on totally non-critical models for far too long. I didn't know this was so easy!

Answer (score 1):

Replace your current strong params with this:

```
def permitted_params
    params.permit(:widget => [:permitted_field, :other_permitted_field])
end
```

More info:
https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources#strong-parameters

Answer (score 0):

I believe your `resource_params` method should be called `permitted_params`. More details on how to handle strong parameters are in [the Inherited Resources documentation](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources#strong-parameters).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a strong parameter related error.  In Rails 4.0, if a parameter is not whitelisted, it fails silently and the object is not created.  I had this error a while back and I don't exactly how to fix it, but can you post your routes.rb file, and include the new and create methods in your controller?  I'm pretty sure your error is in your resource nesting.