# nested attributes for has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm in need to setup attributes for has one association in new and edit actions, so I have this:

Product model

```
has_one :store
accepts_nested_attributes_for :store
```

form

```
= form_tag @product do |f|
  = f.fields_for :store do |store_fields|
    = render 'store_form', :f => store_fields
```

in controller

> params.require(:store).permit(:store).permit!

fields displays, but when I'm submitting form, it doesn't make sense, store association is empty. How problem can be solved?

**UPD**

```
params.require(:product).permit(store_attributes: [:store_id, :supplier_id, :margin, :discount]).permit!
```

Logs:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...", "product"=>{"name"=>"qwefqwefasdf", "description"=>"", "permalink"=>"asdf", "store_attributes"=>{"margin"=>"123", "discount"=>"123"}}, "button"=>"", "id"=>"asdf"}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ok, the right answer is

change

```
  = f.fields_for :store do |store_fields|
```

to

```
  = f.fields_for :store, @vendor.store do |store_fields|
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be:
`= f.fields_for :store_attributes, @vendor.store do |store_fields|`

Answer (score 5):

#### Make sure the params you expect are being sent. (check pluralization)

Can you copy and paste what the params look like from the server side?

```
13:44:29 INFO:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓" .......
```

That will help to get the naming the params correctly

If params naming is correct, but not being accepted for, then try specifying them explicitly

```
params.permit(:product => [:something, :stores_attributes => [:name, :address ]])
```

#### Update:

```
params.permit(:product => [ :name, :description, :permalink, :store_attributes => [:store_id, :supplier_id, :margin, :discount]])
```

#### Nested Attributes Examples:

http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit

Comment: Following this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15919761/rails-4-nested-attributes-unpermitted-parameters I think it should be `params.require(:product).permit(:attributes, :of, :product, store_attributes: [:id, :name])`

Comment: Take a look @ UPD please

Comment: To cosign what [@AJcodex suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20689478/nested-attributes-for-has-one-association/20689553#comment30985361_20689630). Get rid of the last .permit!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the controller in question is `ProductsController`, your strong parameter definition is incorrect.

Try:

```
params.require(:product).permit(:store_attributes)
```

Or, to be more strict, permit only the required attributes:

```
params.require(:product).permit(store_attributes: [ :store_field1, :store_field2 ])
```

Where `:store_field1` and `:store_field2` are the attributes from `store` model that are in  your `form` and you want to permit.

**Update:**

The following should work based on your log output.

```
params.require(:product).permit(:name, :description, :permalink, store_attributes: [ :margin, :discount ])
```

Comment: Take a look @ UPD please

Comment: @Zhirayr, You would not need the extra `.permit!`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the parameters in the console. You should see something like:

```
{ "product" => { "store_attributes" => {  } }
```

Which means you want to `require` :product (you want the product parameters) and permit the correct attributes for the store.

```
params.require(:product).permit(:store_attributes => [ :name, :location, :etc ])
```

When you require(:store) that means you expect a "store" key at the root of the parameters hash, which is not the case (and why your association is coming up empty.)

Comment: Take a look @ UPD please

Comment: get rid of the last `permit!`

Answer (score 0):

no this will not work. If you use nested_attributes with has_one association the these attributes should be written in plain not in the separate array.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).