# All my hidden fields in my form are showing as unpermitted parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have dates which are preset, so I'm trying to hide the field in the form, but when I hide them I get the following:

> Unpermitted parameters: start_date, end_date, id

and so my model validation brings up an error saying it can't be left blank.

However, I can see it is being passed with values:

```
"appointment"=>{"service_id"=>"2", "car_id"=>"1", 
"start_date"=>"Tue Dec 31 2013 09:30:00 GMT 0000 (GMT)",
"end_date"=>"2013-12-31T10:30:00+00:00", 
"garage"=>"0", 
"in_note"=>"", 
"out_note"=>"", 
"id"=>""}, 
"commit"=>"Create"}
```

I notice the formatting problem on start_date, but when I don't hide these parameters, it works fine.

I'm using:

```
<%= f.input :start_date, :as => :hidden %>
<%= f.input :end_date, :as => :hidden %>
```

But have also tried:

```
 <%= f.hidden_field :start_date %>
 <%= f.hidden_field :end_date %>
```

with the same results.

CONTROLLER

```
def new

    @car = params[:car_id];
    @date = DateTime.parse(params[:start_date])

    @appointment = Appointment.new(:end_date => @date + 1.hour, :start_date => @date, :car_id => @car)
    render :json => {:form => render_to_string(:partial => 'form')}
end
```

FORM (needs a bit of tidying up)

```
    <%= simple_form_for(@appointment, :html => { :id => 'event_form' }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>



  <div class="inputs">
<%= f.association :service,
label_method: :name,
value_method: :id %>
<%= f.association :car,
label_method: :make,
value_method: :id %>

    <%= f.hidden_field :start_date %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :end_date %>
    <%= f.input :garage %>
    <%= f.input :in_note %>
    <%= f.input :out_note %>
  </div>

<%=f.hidden_field :id, :value => @appointment.id %>

<p>
<%=f.submit 'Create' %> <span id = "creating_appointments" class="spinner" style = "display:none;">Creating, Please wait...</span>
</p>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

MODEL

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :car
    belongs_to :service
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :service
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :car

    attr_accessor :period, :frequency, :commit_button

    validates_presence_of :car_id, :service_id, :start_date, :end_date
    #validate :validate_timings


    def validate_timings
        p start_date, end_date
        if (start_date > end_date)
            errors[:base] << "Start Time must be less than End Time"
        end
    end

end
```

Comment: Can you add more of your form so we can see context of what you are doing. Also your controller and model would be very useful in investigating the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Without having every detail about your app, it might well be that your attributes are not getting though. Be it lack of `attr_accessible` model declaration or strong parameters declaration in your controller. Have a look at this post to see if you are having a similar problem:

[Rails 4 Nested Attributes Unpermitted Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15919761/rails-4-nested-attributes-unpermitted-parameters)

Comment: I'll check you link now, I have previously ruled out such issues as it works fine if I don't set the fields to hidden, this is leading me to think it's a simple_form issue.