# Trying to add a foreign relationship to my users model with Devise, then update it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

This is for Rails 4.04 and Ruby 2.1. I'd like to allow my users to have addresses. So I generated an address table and gave it columns (NUMBER, STREET, CITY, STATE). Now when I go to the following url, I'd like to be able edit this information:

```
webapp.com/users/edit/
```

However I noticed it only showed the same old information (name, password, email). So I went to the view and added simple_fields for my new relationship so the view now looks like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
 <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true %>
    <%= f.input :name, required: false %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :addresses do |a| %>
        <%= a.input :number %>
        <%= a.input :street %>
        <%= a.input :city %>
        <%= a.input :state %>
        <%= a.input :country %>
  <% end %>
<%end%>
```

However it still doesn't generate the fields needed for address. I think this is because none of my users currently have any addresses attached to their account profile (because this migration was just created). However, in this case there should be blank fields generated so I can ADD address information.

I feel like I need to do something in the Users#Edit action like this

```
@users.each do |user|
        user.address.build
    end
```

Is that right? How can I override the users controller because this was created by Devise and I don't actually have a users controller (I looked for it it and couldn't find it).

UPDATE

Ok, I'm getting closer. I had to create my own controller to override Devise's default registrations controller as explained in the second answer of this stack overflow article:

[Override devise registrations controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller)

So now I am getting into that controller which currently looks like this:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def edit
    super
  end
end
```

However, when I get to my view, it's still SKIPPING the block that starts like this:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :addresses do |a| %>
```

However, if I go manually into my DB and add a record in the addresses table and link it to my currently_signed in user via the foreign key, then the block does not get skipped. So whats the best way to generate this connection if the address record does not yet exist? Is it the build method? e.g.

```
user.address.build
```

in the controller

SOLUTION

Yes, I needed to added this method to my new registrations_controller.rb file

```
def edit
    if resource.addresses.size == 0
      resource.addresses.build
    end
    super
  end
```

It is now working the way I intended it.

Comment: devise doesn't come with a controller. i think there is a way of manually adding it. devise comes with `user model` and `users table` did you make the association of `users` and `addresses`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do it like this:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :address
   before_create :build_address, unless: Proc {|x| x.address.present? } #-> not sure about the if statement
end

#app/models/address.rb
Class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

--

[**Devise *does* come with Controllers**](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/master/app/controllers/devise)

These controllers are not shown in your app (they are installed with the Devise gem, but only visible in production):

```
- confirmations_controller.rb
- omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb
- passwords_controller.rb
- registrations_controller.rb
- sessions_controller.rb
- unlocks_controller.rb
```

--

**You Don't Need Them**

Whilst you *can* override these controllers, you won't need to, as your `edit` action will be tied to the `users` controller:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users

#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
Class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def edit
      @user = User.find params[:id]
   end
end

#app/views/users/edit.html.erb
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
   ...
   <%= f.fields_for :address do |a| %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

---

**Update**

Sorry for not explaining. You *can* use `resources :users` with `devise_for :users`:

```
#config/routes.rb
devise_for :users
resources :users, only: [:edit, :update]
```

If this does not work, you *may* need to change the `path_names` argument for `devise`, like so:

```
#config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, path_names: { sign_in: 'login', password: 'forgot', confirmation: 'confirm', unlock: 'unblock', sign_up: 'register', sign_out: 'logout'}
```

-

**Form**

The form can have `resource`, but I think you need to work out what you're trying to change. If you're trying to change a `devise` object, then use the `resource` helper; but if you're trying to change the `User` model directly - I'd be partial to changing that!

The issue I think you have is if you're using `resource`, it's going to route to `Devise` controller actions. I would try setting `@user` in the `edit` action of your `users controller`, and use the conventional way to update

Comment: Question #1 is you said Class UsersController < ActiveRecord::Base but seems like it should be Class UsersController < ApplicationController. #2 is that the users_controller.rb file didn't exist in my app, I had to create it. #3 is in my routes file I have the line "devise_for :users" and you didn't mention if that should be left in or not in addition to "resources :users" #4 is that in my view I don't have form_for @user.... I have "simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name,", and #5 is the actual error I'm now getting which is "The action 'show' could not be found for UsersController"

Comment: I traced the action back and I can see that its going through a special devise controller in the Gem (class Devise::RegistrationsController < DeviseController). This is the controller that gets used when I go to webapp.com/users/edit/

Comment: Updating my original post

Comment: I didn't quite use the approach you recommended but Im going to select your answer because it was the most thorough and much of it is relevant the the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you didn't made the relation between those models add to `addresses` column called `user_id` and add to user model:

```
has_many :addresses
```

and into addresses:

```
belongs_to :users
```

then in your view you can build this form using nested attributes see this post:

[Rails 4 Nested Attributes Unpermitted Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15919761/rails-4-nested-attributes-unpermitted-parameters)

another option that you can do is to show that `addresses` form after the user already signed in then when he update the form find the user_id with `current_user` and build the record using this id but using strong params in Rails 4 is recommended to solve your issue.