# Rails: Polymorphic assosiation and accepts_nested_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, nested-attributes, polymorphic-associations

The attachment won't save. What I am missing here?
In my application I have a project ,for each project user can upload many assets. The Upload is done by carrier wave.

here are the models

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

   has_many :assets,:as => :assetable,dependent: :destroy
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets, :allow_destroy => true

end


class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :assetable, :polymorphic => true
  mount_uploader :attachment, AttachmentUploader #carrierwave
  validates :attachment, presence: true
  validates :project_id, presence: true
end
```

and these are the actions in my project_controller

```
  def new
     @project = Project.new
     @asset = @project.assets.build
   end 



  def create
      @project = Project.new(project_params)
      @project.assets.build
      respond_to do |format|
          if @project.save
              format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
              format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @project }
          else 
              format.html { render :new }
              format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end 
end


def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(:user_id,  :summary, :start_date,assets_attributes: [:id, :project_id, :attachment,:user_id] )
end
```

this is how the form looks like

```
   <%= form_for @project,:html => {:multipart => true } do |f| %> 
     <% if @project.errors.any? %>
     <div id="error_explanation">
     </div>
     <% end %>
     <%= f.fields_for :assets do |p| %>
         <div class="field">
             <%= p.label :attachment %><br>
             <%= p.file_field :attachment,name: "assets[attachment][]" %>
          </div>
     <% end %>
     <div class="actions">
         <%= f.submit %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: Does your form includes this :  enctype="multipart/form-data" ? Otherwise binary data won't be sent with the post vars.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I have updated the question. So the form is also there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "assets", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "assetable_id"
    t.string   "assetable_type"
    t.string   "attachment"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

create_table "projects", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "user_id"
    t.string   "summary"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

**projects/_form.html.erb**

```
 <%= form_for @project, :html => {:multipart => true } do |f| %>
 <% if @project.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <%= @project.errors.inspect %>
    </div>
 <% end %>

 <%= f.label :summary %>
 <%= f.text_field :summary %>

 <%= f.fields_for :assets do |p| %>
   <div class="field">
     <%= p.label :attachment %><br>
     <%= p.file_field :attachment %>

     <%= p.hidden_field :assetable_id %>
     <%= p.hidden_field :assetable_type %>
    </div>
 <% end %>

 <div class="actions">
     <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**projects_controller.rb**

```
  # GET /projects/new
  def new
    @project = Project.new
    @project.assets.build
  end

  # POST /projects
  # POST /projects.json
  def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
          format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @project }
      else
          format.html { render :new }
          format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:user_id,  :summary, :start_date, assets_attributes: [:id, :assetable_id, :assetable_type, :attachment, :user_id] )
    end
```

**project.rb**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :assets, :as => :assetable, dependent: :destroy
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

**asset.rb**

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :assetable, :polymorphic => true

  mount_uploader :attachment, AttachmentUploader #carrierwave

  validates :attachment, presence: true
  validates :assetable_type, presence: true
end
```

**Aside**

Since you based this question off a previous question you asked I'll just mention: You only want to use a polymorphic association if you intend instances of your asset class to belong to different types of classes (ie. things other than a project).

Comment: Yes I have other models, that I want to use assets for the. That why I need to use polymorphic associations

Comment: I have a problem, when I want to upload a file I get this error, Assets attachment can't be blank

Comment: You have a validation in your asset class to ensure it has a present attachment (validates :attachment, presence: true) You're getting that error because your form submission isn't including an image.  Are you clicking the file upload button and selecting an image? If so check your development.log file for errors from CarrierWave and open a new question if something is wrong there.  Don't forget to accept answers if you feel they answered your question