# Rails - Nested form with complex params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I need to create a campaign with given prizes. My models already are related and accepting nested attributes.

View:

```
      <%= form_for @campaign, remote: true do |f| %>
       <% 5.times do |i| %>
        <%= f.fields_for :prizes do |prize_form| %>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= prize_form.label "prize #{i + 1}" %>
            <%= prize_form.text_field :name %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
     <% end %>
```

Which generates:

```
<input id="campaign_prizes_attributes_0_name" name="campaign[prizes_attributes][0][name]" type="text">
<input id="campaign_prizes_attributes_1_name" name="campaign[prizes_attributes][1][name]" type="text">
<input id="campaign_prizes_attributes_2_name" name="campaign[prizes_attributes][2][name]" type="text">
<input id="campaign_prizes_attributes_3_name" name="campaign[prizes_attributes][3][name]" type="text">
<input id="campaign_prizes_attributes_4_name" name="campaign[prizes_attributes][4][name]" type="text">
```

In my controller I have this

```
class CampaignsController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :html, :js
    def index
        @campaigns = Campaign.all
    end

    def new
        @campaign = Campaign.new
        @campaign.prizes.build
    end

    def create
        @campaign = Campaign.new(campaign_params)
        @campaign.prizes.build
    end

    def campaign_params
        params.require(:campaign).permit(:name, :date_start, :date_end, :status, :rules, prizes_attributes: [name: []])
    end
end
```

No matter what I do, I always get this error:

```
Unpermitted parameters: name
```

I need to make each campaign have a varying ammount of prizes, but I'm not able to make this work. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `campaign_params` method should  be:

```
 def campaign_params
      params.require(:campaign).permit(:name, 
                                                                      :date_start,
                                                                      :date_end, 
                                                                      :status,
                                                                      :rules,
                                                                      prizes_attributes: [ :name ])
 end
```

[`How permit nested attributes`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15919761/rails-4-nested-attributes-unpermitted-parameters)

Comment: I thought because the prizes were an array, it would be necassary to specify it. Great mistake, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your campaign_params are wrong

`prizes_attributes: [name: []]`

must be

`prizes_attributes: [:name]`

Comment: Thanks for the answer!