# Getting Unpermitted parameter warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I am using Rails 5.2.1 and ruby 2.5.0 for the development of my new project.
I need to permit user params which has the following structure

```
{
   "user_id": 1
   "name": "John",
   "pets": [
              {
                "id": 1,
                "count": 5
              },
              {
                "id": 2,
                "count": 3
              },
            ]
}
```

My User model has following lines

```
  has_many :pets, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pets
```

and in the controller

```
 params.require(:user).permit(:user_id, :name, pets_attributes: %i(id, count))
```

But when I post the above json request it produces the following error

```
Unpermitted parameter: :pets
```

I couldn't find any solution. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested attributes unpermitted parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15919761/nested-attributes-unpermitted-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, are the params being sent in this format?: `{user: {user_id: ...}}`

Irrespective of the format sent, one issue with your code is pets_attributes should be as follows:

`pets_attributes: %i(id count)` or `pets_attributes: [:id, :count]`

So

```
params.require(:user).permit(:user_id, :name, pets_attributes: %i(id count))
```

OR

```
params.require(:user).permit(:user_id, :name, pets_attributes:[:id, :count])
```

Hope this helped.