# Error when submitting form: Nested attributes unpermitted parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've tried the solutions on [this other stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15919761/nested-attributes-unpermitted-parameters) but they aren't working.

I'm getting this error when submitting my form: `Unpermitted parameter: organization_required_fields`

Any help would be appreciated.

I have the following models:

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :organization_required_fields
  has_many :fields, through: :organization_required_fields

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :organization_required_fields, allow_destroy: true
end

class OrganizationRequiredField < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  belongs_to :field
end

class Field < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :organization_required_fields
  has_many :organizations, through: :organization_required_fields
end
```

My controller:

```
def update
...
  @organization.update(organization_params)
...
end

private
def set_organization
  @organization = Organization.find_by_id(params[:id])
  ...
end

def organization_params
  params.require(:organization).permit(:name, :user_id, organization_required_fields_attributes: [:id, :organization_id, :field_id, :_destroy])
end
```

My form view

```
...
= f.select :organization_required_fields, options_for_select(@fields.collect {|rf| [ rf.name.titleize, rf.id ] }, @organization.fields.collect{ |orf| orf.id }),{ :prompt => "Please select"},{ :multiple => true, :size => 15 }
...
```

Comment: I don't really get why you would add a separate `OrganizationRequiredField` model and association unless the definition of the fields attached to an organization are not a developer concern (not defined by the db schema) and must be user editable.

Comment: That is why i added the model. They are user edited.

Answer (score 0):

I actually changed a lot by following this [rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes-revised?autoplay=true)

I also had to change the organization_params to

`params.require(:organization).permit(:name, :user_id, { field_ids: []})`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`fields_for`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for) in your form.