# Unpermitted parameter :supervisor

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a website where users can input hours, and supervisors can approve or deny them, but I keep getting this error:
    Unpermitted parameter: :supervisor

I've tried changing the has_many relationships, changing the parameters of the supervisors like [Nested attributes unpermitted parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15919761/nested-attributes-unpermitted-parameters) said, but to no avail.

my hours_controller.rb (I'm getting the error here)

```
   def create
       @hour = current_user.hours.build(hour_params)
       @supervisor = Supervisor.find_by(params[:email])
       if @hour.save
          flash[:info] = "Waiting for approve"
          redirect_to current_user
       end
   end


   private

   def hour_params
      params.require(:hour).permit(:content, :approved)
   end
```

my hour.rb

```
class Hour < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :supervisor
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :content, :inclusion => 1..100
  validates :approved, presence: true, default: false
end
```

my supervisor_controller.rb

```
class SupervisorsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @supervisor = Supervisor.new
  end

  def create
   Supervisor.new = Supervior.create(supervisor_params)
    if @supervisor.save
      flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def home
  end

  def hours
  end

  private

  def supervisor_params
    params.require(:supervisor).permit(:id, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :address, :telephone, :role, :organization, :password, :password_confirmation, :signature, { hour: [:content, :approved]})
  end


end
```

my supervisor.rb

```
class Supervisor < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :hours, dependent: :destroy
    validates :first_name, presence: true
    validates :last_name,  presence: true
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, presence: true, format: {with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
    validates :address, presence: true
    validates :telephone, presence: true
    validates :role, presence: true
    validates :organization, presence: true
    has_secure_password
    validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }


end
```

and my html for the actual form

```
<%= form_for @hour, url: hours_path do |hour_builder| %>
   <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: hour_builder.object %>

      <%= hour_builder.label :content, "Hours to input" %>
      <%= hour_builder.text_field :content, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= hour_builder.simple_fields_for @supervisor do |supervisor_builder| %>
         <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: supervisor_builder.object %>


         <%= supervisor_builder.label :first_name, "First name of supervisor" %>
         <%= supervisor_builder.text_field :first_name, class: 'form-control' %>
         <%= supervisor_builder.label :email, "Email of supervisor" %>
         <%= supervisor_builder.text_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
         <%= supervisor_builder.label :telephone, "Telephone number of Supervisor" %>
         <%= supervisor_builder.text_field :telephone, class: 'form-control' %>

         <% end %>
      <%= hour_builder.submit 'Log Hours', class: 'btn btn-success' %> 

<% end %>

`
```

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish ?. Looking at the code, the form hits your `HoursController#create` action. And you only permit the `content` and `approved` params that come in you `hour` resource in the params. You're not permitting anything about the `supervisor` that comes from the form. But in your `HoursController#create` action you're not doing anything with the Supervisor stuff because you're not using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in your `Hour` model. Or not sure what you're trying to do here. Perhaps you think that the from will go to both controllers ?, that's not true.

Comment: To me, it looks like you're posting this hour form with a supervisor key in your hours controller, which is showing unpermitted since you don't have that keyword in your strong params.

Comment: @fanta I thought that the form would go to both controllers, so i changed the Hour model to `accepts_nested_attributes_for :supervisor` and used @dharmesh's code and I'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers, I used all of them to help me, but here is what I did in full:

first: I added this line to my hour.rb

**hour.rb**

`attr_accessor :supervisor`

Second: I added a migration for the hours model to use the supervisor model as a reference

`$ rails g migration add_supervisor_to_hours supervisor:references`

Third: I changed the hour_params in my hours_controller.rb

**hours_controller.rb**

```
def hour_params
   params.require(:hour).permit(:content, :email, 
   supervisor: [:id,:first_name, :email, :telephone])
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are passing the supervisor params nested inside hours params. Whereas in controller you have not permitted supervisor params in your hours controller.

update your hours controller to

```
def hour_params
  params.require(:hour).permit(:content, :approved, supervisor_attributes: [:id, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :telephone])
end
```

This is based on the form you have created. I think you need to rework on the associations between hours and supervisors and users.

My suggesstion would be to change the hour model to accept nested_attributes for supervisor model and make changes to the params to allow supervisor attributes along with hour params.

Comment: I've tried this code and didn't change, it still told my there `Unpermitted parameter: :supervisor` and I also tried changing `supervisor_attributes` to `supervisor` and it gave me an `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch` error

Answer (score 0):

Try to merge params

def company_params
    params[:company].merge!(users_attributes: {'0': user_params.to_h })
    params.require(:company).permit(
      :name, :contact_person_name, :email,
      :contact_person_number, :terms_and_conditions,
      users_attributes: %i[
        id first_name last_name password
        password_confirmation phone_number
      ]
    )
  end

def user_params
    params[:user].merge!(phone_number: params[:company][:contact_person_number])
    params.require(:user).permit(
      :first_name, :last_name, :password,
      :password_confirmation, :phone_number
    )
  end

In my case company has many user.
I hope work for u.